# Python: Scrapy returning all html following element instead of just html of element

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am having an issue where Scrapy is behaving unexpectedly.

I wrote a simple function months ago that returns a list of items at a given xpath.

```
def get_html(response,path):
    sel = Selector(text = response.page_source)
    time.sleep(.2)
    items = sel.xpath(path).getall()
    return items
```

Usage Example:

```
<body>
    <div id="1">Some Text</div>
    <div id="2">Different Text</div>
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
</body>
```

If I wanted to get all of the div elements, I would write this:

```
get_html(response,'//div')
```

I expect, and have previously received, this output

```
['<div id="1">Some Text</div>',
 '<div id="2">Different Text</div>']
```

However, now when I call this method, I receive this output

```
['<div id="1">Some Text</div><div id="2">Different Text</div><a href="#">Some link</a></body>',
 '<div id="2">Different Text</div><a href="#">Some link</a></body>']
```

The problem isn't due to a change in the webpage I was scraping, I saved the source code when I originally scraped and it is identical to the source code I see on the webpage today. This problem exists across multiple websites I've tried to scrape. I'm not sure what the problem is, or how to fix it. I either need to fix the problem, or replace the function with another function that behaves identically.

I understand there are ways I could split the strings and remove the unwanted data, however I have used this function in 100+ modules, and do not want to risk breaking those by hardcoding a solution like that. I need to understand why the output of the function has changed, despite nothing about the source code changing.

Edit:

Per comments below, here is exactly what I enter into the console to produce this result. Please let me know how I can begin to diagnose why this is happening if it's not reproduceable for others. I am using Spyder version 4.2.5, Python 3.8.5, Scrapy 2.4.1.

```
In[1]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In[2]: text = """<body>
        <div id="1">Some Text</div>
        <div id="2">Different Text</div>
        <a href="#">Some link</a>
    </body>"""

In[3]: sel = Selector(text=text)

In[4]: items = sel.xpath('//div').getall()

In[5]: items
Out[5]: 
['<div id="1">Some Text</div>\n        <div id="2">Different Text</div>\n        <a href="#">Some link</a>\n    </body></html>\n',
 '<div id="2">Different Text</div>\n        <a href="#">Some link</a>\n    </body></html>\n']
```

Comment: first check what you have in `response.page_source`  because problem can be `HTML`

Comment: using `sleep()` is useless when you work with `response.page_source`

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Better show minimal working code which we could copy and run. And use real URL which makes problem.

Comment: I can get similar result (but not the same) when I use `&lt;/div>` instead of `</div>` in HTML. Browser could displays it as `</div>` but for selector it is not `</div>` so it get all to the end of HTML.

Comment: I've added an edit that has the exact steps I take to produce the problem.

Comment: I created similar code on my own :) I copied your code and run it and I get correct result. But I run it directly in Python `python script.py` without `Spyder` and `IPython`. Try it without `Spyder` and `IPython` to see if problem makes `IDE`. The only idea that the is something wrong with char `<` in `</div>` - maybe there is char similar to `<` because I can get similar result only if I use `&lt;` instead of `<` in `</div>`

Comment: @furas it does work correctly when I run it directly in python. I guess I'll have to try and fix my Spyder/Anaconda installation somehow. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem appears to be fixed after a fresh install of Anaconda. Not sure what caused it to appear in the first place, here's hoping it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with MacOS, Anaconda, Python 3.7 and Scrapy 2.4.1. I found that creating a new Conda environment with Python 3.9 and Scrapy 2.5.0 fixed the issue.