# scrapy returning more than the selected element

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

The response I get from a css query in scrapy is the element I have requested **PLUS the entire rest of page.**

By way of example I will use the actually official scrappy tutorial found here:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

> [image]
>
> [image]

This is the instructions as well as the expected output according to the tutorial.

Below is the output I get...

[image]

As you can see, the exact same command is returning the entire html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I get the same result if I do it via XPATH... pls help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Reinstall Anaconda and Scrapy fixed the issue. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68534922/7481578)